# Using ikiwiki via command line: Workflow and permission problem

Tags: permissions, git, ikiwiki

I use my ikiwiki for personal notes only on my laptop locally (the html pages are under `~/public_html/mywiki`) and now I am trying to edit it with emacs and push from command line.

I have some questions about this:

1. Is the following workflow correct:

`cd ~/mywiki`

edit and save `~/mypage.mdwm` with `emacs`

```
git add ~/mypage.mdwm
git commit -m "mypage edit"
git push
```

Since I also sometimes want to edit it from the web interface, I tested it and noticed that it doesn't seem that I have to pull before editing. If I save an edit from the web interface the directory `~/mywiki` is updated magically without using `git pull`.

Is this correct so far or is there a better workflow?

2. After editing and saving the page from the web interface it is saved with root permissions in `~/mywiki` how can I make ikiwiki to save everything with my username as group and owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ad question 1:**

This seems to be correct. If you set `git_wrapper` to `git_wrapper: /home/user/mywiki/.git/hooks/post-commit` (instead of `git_wrapper: /home/user/mywiki.git/hooks/post-update`  you don't need the push step.

You may also think about another working clone of your wiki. But as long as you have a single user setup and you don't edit via web interface and editor at the same time, it should be fine to work inside `scrdir` as you described. See also this question: [Why do I need 3 git repositories for ikiwiki if I want to commit locally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136493/why-do-i-need-3-git-repositories-for-ikiwiki-if-i-want-to-commit-locally))

**ad question 2:**

I am not quite sure where the problem comes from, maybe that you did run `ikiwiki` with `sudo` during setup. I suggest the following to fix it:

1. Make sure, that `public_html` is owned by you (`sudo chmod myuser:myuser ~/public_html`)
2. Resetup the wiki via cloning:

   - Clone the bare repository: `git clone --bare ~/mywiki.git ~/newiki.git` (even if the files in `mywiki.git` are owned by `root` the files in `~/newiki.git` will owened by `myuser`)
   - `cp ~/mywiki.git/config ~/newiki.git/config`
   - Make new `srcdir`: `git clone ~/newiki.git ~/newiki` (`~/newiki` will be your new `srcdir`)
3. Make new config file: `cp ~/mywiki.setup ~/newiki.setup` and rename all occurences of `mywiki` with `newiki`.
4. Then run (without sudo): `ikiwiki --setup newiki.setup --getctime`
5. Test in your browser: `127.0.0.1/~myuser/newiki`

If everything works you may (after an backup) delete `mywiki` and rename `newiki` to `mywiki` if you want.